# Obfuscate just one class file in Android

Tags: java, android, class

So i have project which is going to be public (including source file). and in it im using my personal "api" which i created with time (nothing too special, just a lot of time savers) and i would like to make that particular .class file(s) very hard to re-use by someone without permission. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just obsucating all the classes? The final .apk file will be smaller. IMHO, if you obfuscate one class, you need to obfuscate at least the classes that use that class.

Comment: But i need the users to be able to edit the main class files (like changing some parameters or adding more content, change the visuals etc). and i know its nothing special, but it has some paid code in it, like ftp connections, smtp, and a lot more of networking tools. the project isnt supposed to be open source, just to serve as a "demo" for my skills.

Answer (score 1):

Make your own obfuscated jar file that is from just that class and include that in your project.

Comment: .................................................... i feel stupid now.. for some reason i didnt thought of that........ 1 year of android experience and sometimes the trivial java stuff isnt near of my mind..

Comment: That's why we all like having each other to bounce ideas off of... We lose perspective.